# Paginação de resultados em php com limite de páginas

Tags: php, paginação

Possuo um site o qual preciso exibir diversas imagens por página. Limitei essa exibição em 16 itens por página, o que resultou em 10 páginas. Como o site também será exibido em *mobile*, ficará estranho se a paginação ultrapassar 10 páginas, sendo que eu gostaria que ficasse limitado há apenas 10 e o usuário clicaria na seta para ir para a décima primeira. Já tentei adaptar alguns exemplos que vi por aqui, mas sem sucesso.

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "countries");

$q1 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM countrie");

$count = mysqli_num_rows($q1);


$rowsperpage = 5;

$page = $_REQUEST['p'];

if( $page == 0 or $page == ''){
    $page = 1;
}

$page = $page - 1;

$p = $page * $rowsperpage;

$query = "SELECT * FROM countrie limit ".$p." , " .$rowsperpage;



$run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while( $rs = mysqli_fetch_array($run) ){

        echo $rs['id'].'->' .$rs['country_name'].' <br/>';
}


    if( $_REQUEST['p'] > 1){
    $prev_page = $_REQUEST['p'] - 1;

echo '<span style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="LoadData('.$prev_page.')">Back</span>';
}

    $check = $p + $rowsperpage;

    if( $count > $check){
    $next_page = $_REQUEST['p']+1;
echo '<span style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="LoadData('.$next_page.')">Next</span>';
}


    $limit = $count / $rowsperpage;

    $limit = ceil($limit);

    echo '</br></br>';
    for( $i=1; $i<=$limit; $i++ ){

        if( $i==$_REQUEST['p']){
            echo '<strong>' .$i.'<strong>';
            }
            else{
                echo '<span style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="LoadData('.$i.')">'.$i.'</span>';
            }


    }

?>
```

Comment: O que você quer é exibir os links das páginas, tipo: `[<] 3 4 5 6 7 [>]`? No caso, deveria ficar limitado a 10 links apenas?

Comment: relacionada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/200830/pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-resultados/200843#200843

Comment: sim, exatamente, sendo que do decimo primeiro em diante ficaria sendo acessivel pela setinha